# Assign variable from $http .success function to $scope.variable

Tags: angularjs

$scope.restaurants variable is emty. how to pass data to $scope.restaurants?

```
FoodSearchControllers.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
//restoranai
$http.post('http://appdev.milasevicius.com/server/index.php', {
    "query": "SELECT * FROM n01_restaurant"
}).success(function(data, status) {
    $scope.restaurants = data;
}).error(function(data, status) {
    $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
    $scope.status = status;
});

console.log($scope.restaurants);
}]);
```

Also, controller is called twice. Why is that?

Comment: It is empty because it the call is asynchronous. But will be filled upon successful response (assuming your back-end is configured properly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `console.log` is called at a point where the `$http` call might not have returned yet. The `post` is an async call so if you move your `console.log` in your `success` function, you should see it. In short, `$scope.restaurants` is mostly likely being populated but you're trying to check it too early.